# Checkbox issues in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, django

I'm making a checkbox in Django, but I'm seeing when I render the checkbox a nicely rendered checkbox pops up which is good, but also a traditional looking checkbox comes along for the ride. My CSS is the following:

```
input[type=checkbox]:before { display:inline-block; content:""; width:20px; height:20px; background:red; border:solid 3px #e2e2e2; margin:0px;}
input[type=checkbox]:checked:before { display:inline-block; background:green; width:20px; height:20px; border:solid 3px #e2e2e2; margin:0px;}​
```

I know this isn't really a Django issue - I'm creating my own render function so I can spit out HTML in any format, but I don't know why I get two functioning textboxes. Here is my Django render for each option. This is taken and adapted from the render function on CheckBoxWidget - I.e. wanted to employ some formatting to it hence I created my own function with a different render function.

```
for i, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(chain(self.choices, choices)):
            # If an ID attribute was given, add a numeric index as a suffix,
            # so that the checkboxes don't all have the same ID attribute.
            if has_id:
                final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='%s_%s' % (attrs['id'], i))
                label_for = format_html(' for="{0}"', final_attrs['id'])
            else:
                label_for = ''

            cb = CheckboxInput(final_attrs, check_test=lambda value: value in str_values)
            option_value = force_text(option_value)
            rendered_cb = cb.render(name, option_value)
            option_label = force_text(option_label)
            r = i % 2
            if len(option_label) > 40:
            option_label = force_text(option_label).split('[')[0]
        if len(option_label) > 40:
            option_label = force_text(option_label)[0:40]

            output.append(format_html(row_label[r]+'<li class="option table"> <label {0} > <div class="cell" id="left"> <div class="icon profile" data-icon-name="profile"> </div> </div> <div class="cell" id="center">{2}</div><div class="cell" id="right"><div class="styled-check"><div class="check"></div>{1}</label></div></div></li></div>',
                                      label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))
        output.append('')
```

Comment: What does your Django Form look like?
What does your template look like?

Comment: @Filly, I got the example CSS from one of the online builders.

Comment: What is the checkbox for? You should make a Django form and not add your own html. It is likely that you are adding an extra field.

Comment: @Siecje - extra field?

Comment: You said you see an extra checkbox. You should have a Django Form class.

Comment: Wow, that's some spaghetti code there. :-). First guess, you're looping through twice. What's the size of the result of enumerate(self.choices, choices)?

Comment: @professorDante This is the render function from actual Django widget that I have modified! I have only changed the HTML spit out and the lines to cut down the string length.

Comment: @Siecje What do you mean? Django form class?

Comment: Again, whats the size of the result of chaining self.choices, choices? It's a loop, so you're looping through twice, hence two checkboxes. Django will show a default checkbox if you have a set of choices, unless blank=False and default value given in model.

Comment: @professorDante This has nothing to do with the loop at all. All works fine and tested. Of course its the standard code taken from the Widget. Thanks anyway. This is a style sheet issue. Somehow I'm getting two boxes out for every <input>

Comment: Not sure how you can say it's a CSS issue - CSS doesn't create new markup, which is what you have if you say you have 2 checkboxes not 1. Good luck in finding it!

Comment: @professorDante because the rendering is fine. The stylesheet must be at fault, because I've stripped things back without the style sheet and I render a single checkbox, so that has to be the acid test, right?